# Pandas ewm conditional variable span

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to find the ewm mean() over a variable span. The span varies depending on the sum of another column.

Eg let’s say I have two columns A and B

I want the exponentially weighted mean of B over the number of periods of B where the sum of A during those periods met some threshold.

Let’s say that threshold was >= 4:

A   B  … desired outcome

1    2

1    2

2    3  … ewm of last 3 rows of B

4    1  … ewm of last 1 row of B

1    1  … ewm of last 2 rows of B

3    1  … ewm of last 2 rows of B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3], "B": [2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1]})
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```py
ALPHA = 0.9
THRESHOLD = 4

mask = df["A"].cumsum() >= THRESHOLD

new_df = df[mask].reset_index(drop=True)
new_df.at[0, "EWMA"] = new_df.at[0, "B"]

for i, row in new_df.iterrows():
    if not i:
        continue
    new_df.at[i, "EWMA"] = (
        ALPHA * new_df.at[i, "B"] + (1 - ALPHA) * new_df.at[i - 1, "EWMA"]
    )

new_df = pd.concat([df[~mask], new_df], ignore_index=True)
```

Then:

```py
print(new_df)
# Output

   A  B   EWMA
0  1  2    NaN
1  1  2    NaN
2  2  3  3.000
3  4  1  1.200
4  1  1  1.020
5  3  1  1.002
```